# ion-select não recarrega quando eu mudo de tab

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Quando eu mudo de tab, e volto para a tab antiga, que contem o ion-select, o campo fica setado nulo, sem nada marcado, mesm que a página contine carregando de acordo com a variável populada.

```
<ion-header color="primary">
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Planilha</ion-title>
    <ion-item color="primary">
      <ion-label>Períodos</ion-label>
      <ion-select [(ngModel)]="periodoSelecionado" (ionChange)="filtraPeriodo()">
        <ion-option *ngFor="let p of periodos" [value]="p">{{p.nome}}</ion-option>
        <b>p.nome</b>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-navbar>
  <ion-searchbar color="primary" (ionInput)="getItems($event)"></ion-searchbar>
</ion-header>
```

Neste caso, quando eu mudo a tab, o p.nome não recarrega no momento em que eu volto pra tab. Apenas se eu a marcar de novo.

Comment: Recomendo que para um maior número de pessoas ter acesso a sua pergunta, coloque a pergunta em português. Ou coloque está pergunta no site da Stackoverflow.com

Comment: Sim. Não vi que estava no português.